# Can I merge two keys specs requiring the same unqualified key?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

In the same namespace I define the following specs:

```clj
(s/def :foo/x string?)
(s/def :foo/o (s/keys :req-un [:foo/x]))

(s/valid? :foo/o {:x "true"})
;=> true

(s/def :bar/x boolean?)
(s/def :bar/o (s/keys :req-un [:bar/x]))

(s/valid? :bar/o {:x true})
;=> true
```

Both `:foo/o` and `:bar/o` require different unqualified keys. (I just didn't include them to keep things simple.)

Now I want to create `:baz/o` from `:foo/o` and `:bar/o` and went for the following spec: (still in the same namespace)

```clj
(s/def :baz/o (s/merge :foo/o :bar/o))
```

Assuming that in case of key collisions `:bar/o` would take precedence (which is what I want). However the resulting spec rejects both strings and booleans:

```clj
(s/valid? :baz/o {:x true})
;=> false
(s/valid? :baz/o {:x "true"})
;=> false
```

Here are the results from `s/explain`:

```clj
(s/explain :baz/o {:x "true"})
; "true" - failed: boolean? in: [:x] at: [:x] spec: :bar/x

(s/explain :baz/o {:x true})
; true - failed: string? in: [:x] at: [:x] spec: :foo/x
```

It does seem like `s/merge` has created a predicate for `:x` that I can't satisfy.

In case of "collision" `:bar/o` should take precedence. How can I achieve that? (I'm on Clojure 1.10)

Comment: not sure why it doesn't work, but you might be better off defining a new spec with s/or.
That way you can tell if :foo/o or :bar/o was found

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer Hey thanks for your comment. The problem is that I don't want to match one or the other. I need to produce a spec that is the union of both. In case of "spec collision" I am happy for the last spec of the merge to take over.

Comment: not sure I understand the use case sufficiently. 
If you have `(s/def :foobar/x (s/or :foo :foo/x :bar :bar/x)`
You can use that in `(s/def :baz/o (s/keys :req-un [:foobar/x]))`
If you want precedence, you might have to use your own predicate

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer Ah right I see what you mean now! That's very interesting actually; I'll try that. Still interested to know why I'm seeing this weird behaviour though! :)

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer Just in case it changes anything I posted the results from `s/explain`.

Comment: merge might just use `(s/and)` internally and since `:foo/x` and `:bar/x` are mutually exclusive, spec will always return false

Comment: Could you post your real code? It would be interesting to know how you got to this issue of having to spec the same key differently, and having to merge specs with that common key. Off-the-bat I'd propose the solution of handling this key separately from the other keys, so that you don't arrive to this conflict.